# missing values while using pandas datareader from FRED

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datareader, pandas-datareader

when I use DataReader to scrape data from FRED, there are some NaN values in my DataFrame, however, in FRED official websites, their data and graphs seem to be complete without missing. so I wonder what causes the NaN values to appear in my DataFrame? and how to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
style.use('dark_background')
prev3=620
end3=dt.datetime.today().date()
st3=end-pd.to_timedelta(prev3,unit='d')

tgt=['DFII5','DGS5','DFII10','DFII20','DFII30','GOLDAMGBD228NLBM','USD3MTD156N','USD12MD156N','FEDFUNDS']

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax1=ax.twinx()
tgt=['USD3MTD156N','USD12MD156N','GOLDAMGBD228NLBM','DGS5']
#draw lines
interest=pd.DataFrame()

for i in tgt:
    interest[i]=web.DataReader(i,'fred',st3,end3)[i]
interest['GOLDAMGBD228NLBM']=1/interest['GOLDAMGBD228NLBM']*1000
for i in tgt:
    if i!='GOLDAMGBD228NLBM':
        ax.plot(interest[i],label=i+'(L)',linewidth=0.8)
    else:
        ax1.plot(interest[i],label=i+'(R)',color='r',linewidth=1,linestyle=':')
#draw stackplots
dfii=['DFII5','DFII10','DFII20','DFII30']
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in dfii:
    df[i]=web.DataReader(i,'fred',st3,end3)[i]
for i in df:
    ax.stackplot(df.index,df[i],labels=df.columns,alpha=0.3)


ax.legend(loc=1)
ax1.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the ticker `DGS5` (from your list above) for the month of September, 2020?

- Monday, September 7, 2020 was a US holiday, so FRED has NaN for this ticker/date.
- To remove the 'break' in the plot, you could drop the NaN values before plotting.